# MVVM Pattern in Swift

Tags: swift, mvvm

I have a concept question about MVVM. I'm learning this pattern in swift 3.

This is my situation:
I have a screen with a list of users. The UserViewModel has a property that is a list of users, but the controller shouldn't know about the User model. I read that controller shouldn't know absolutely nothing about the models.

1. If the controller requests data from a user of this list, this data must be a dictionary of data or can be a User model?
2. Then, the UserViewModel must contain also the same properties than the User model?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the controller requests data from a user of this list, this data must be a dictionary of data or can be a User model?

Data can be the `UserModel`.

> Then, the UserViewModel must contain also the same properties than the User model?

Hhm. Of course not. Why `UserViewModel` should have same properties that `UserModel` have? There is no any reason for that.

For purpose when you need to return some `userModel.name` property to controller, you can and should get this only from property of `UserModel`, i.e. get the right `UserModel` from `ViewModel` and than get the property:

```
func controllerFunc() {
    let userModel = viewModel.getUserModelFromList()
    print(userModel.name)
}
```

But in case when you need to prepare value for controller, you can create property in `ViewModel`, that contains some sort of modification for `UserModel`'s property. And controller should get property from `ViewModel`, not from `UserModel`.

> I read that controller shouldn't know absolutely nothing about the models.

Well, ideally - yes. Also, should be mentioned that `ViewModel` shouldn't know anything about UI components, i.e. `ViewModel` shouldn't have `import UIKIt` statement.

For example, if you need an `UIImage`, you should return name (`String` type) of image from `ViewModel` and create `UIImage` object in controller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About the questions of the properties, I was thinking this because if the controller should not know about the model, I need something to store the properties, and I followed this tutorial http://candycode.io/a-practical-mvvm-example-in-swift-part-1/ . One more thing. If a viewmodel has to work with an image, then we can not use UIImage because is inside UIKit, right? Should I use Data?

Comment: @AlbertoGarcíaVallbona, i updated my answer for all your new questions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation @pacification :)

Comment: @AlbertoGarcíaVallbona, no problem)

Comment: The answer is not correct. In MVVM, the "Model" represents an _interface_ to a model aka some sort of data source, or data provider. So, a view _never_ sees a model value directly. The view sees a "binding", which can be a "view state" (DOM, XAML, etc.)  which _can be_  a function of the model's value: `(Model) -> ViewState`.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM:

**Model**: Will be the Schema of your Request and API response

**View**:  Viewcontroller will watch for the change published by the View Model

**ViewModel**: Will broadcast the change/result/response coming from the API

***In Swift:***

To Update the ViewController about the change in Model from the ViewModel is done through Observer Pattern.

ViewModel will publish and update the Model object and send the message through observer that a change has taken place.

The Viewcontroller on the other hand would execute the binding function for update the UI with the Published objects from View Model

***In SwiftUI***:

It has its own Pub-Sub pattern, which can be achieved by *Published* objects and StateObject/ObservedObject property wrappers.

Here view model Publishes the Model Object using `@Published`. View Model can only Publish if it is inheriting from Observable Protocol. The Published Model becomes a publisher that emits the data.

In the view side, `@StateObjects, @ObservedObjects` are both used to hold the published values so that it can be used when the view is redrawn.